# Why is PHP $_REQUEST array empty?

Tags: php, nginx, request

I installed nginx on Ubuntu Hardy and immediately realized that the PHP scripts were getting empty request arrays, ie whether GET or POST nothing was coming through, even the $_REQUEST array was empty.

When I switch back to Apache it was all fine.

The installation nginx version is  0.6.35-0ubuntu1.1~hardy1 and PHP is PHP Version 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.10.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you using rewrite or redirect rules?

Comment: No, there is not rewrites or redirects

Comment: This can also happen if there is a folder with the same name as the path being redirected if mod_rewrite or equivalent exists. The GET parameters get swallowed in that case. Check for a matching folder name if using apache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if this set in your "location"-section for your fastcgi-module

```
 fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpFcgiModule

Comment: I disable the basic fastcgi_params file from inclusion, because I didn't know how may were needed. Worth learning about though.

Answer (score 7):

It's a feature of the `try_files command` in nginx that the `query_string` is not passed automatically to the rewritten file but instead must be passed explicitly. Because of this `_$SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is always empty, and so the the variables `$_REQUEST` and `$_GET` are also not set.

From the [Nginx documentation:](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files)

> Unlike with rewrite, $args are not automatically preserved if the
>   fallback is not a named location. If you need args preserved, you must
>   do so explicitly:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

or with just the arguments

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

If you want to guarantee to get the original arguments then use `$query_string` which is the same as `$args` except that `$query_string` is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the [variables_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) in php config file used by nginx.

Comment: The variables_order is EGPCS. It is set to the default

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if Apache has `LimitRequestBody` (see [core](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)) or `SecRequestBodyLimit` (see [mod_security](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity)) set and the request body is larger than said limit.